Can I visit the UK when my visa application is being processed as an EU citizen?
I am an EU citizen, and I have applied for a long-term (student) visa to the UK from outside. Unfortunately, it turned out that I also need to visit the UK for a few days (less than a week) while my visa application is still being processed. Can I enter (and leave) it using my EU passport as a visitor without interfering with the (student) visa application?

Yes, this should be fine.  There is  a chance that the immigration officer will investigate whether you're trying to enter as a visitor to get around any difficulty or delay in the student visa application.  This should not cause a problem at all, assuming

You won't be engaging in your course of studies during the visit (no instruction, lessons, classes, lectures, etc.), and
You are clearly planning to leave after a week and return later as a student only after you have obtained the student visa.

Most likely the officer will ask you the purpose of your trip and how long you plan to stay, and that will be it.  If the officer notices your pending visa application and asks about it, just tell the truth about your visit and the reasons for doing it now rather than waiting until you travel as a student.  Don't make anything up.  It doesn't need to be an imperative reason -- it could just be "I wanted to do it now because I would rather do it in the summer."  The officer doesn't need ironclad proof that you will leave before the week is out, just a sense that you're telling the truth when you say that you are.
Enjoy your trip!

Thanks a lot! I will then just prepare some proof that I am not planning on staying after entering as a visitor
